# Cant access PS3 FTP via LAN through router

Tags: router, ftp, routing, ps3

I can't access the FTP server on my PS3 through LAN from my PC (PC - Router - PS3). WiFi FTP access works fine. The router is a TP-LINK TL-WR740N running on dd-wrt. Setting up port forwarding and granting the DMZ to the PS3 IP address had no effect.

Comment: "wifi ftp access" works through the same router?

Comment: yes, work perfetly